# How can I download images to populate my collectionviewcell JSON?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

```
//Parsing JSON Oké
    let parsedData : [String:AnyObject]
    do{
        parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
        guard let results = parsedData["results"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else {
            print("There is a problem related to results fetch"); return }
        for res in results {

            var dataMi : Data!
            //For the image data
            let urlOfthePic = URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92\(res["backdrop_path"]!)")
            let downLoadPicTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlOfthePic!, completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in
                guard let data = data else {print("second"); return}
                dataMi = data
                self.mov.movImage = UIImage(data: dataMi)!
                print(dataMi)
            });downLoadPicTask.resume()
            print("2:", dataMi)
            //Error is occured because of the "nil" 
            //self.mov.movImage = UIImage(data:dataMi)!

            self.mov.movTitle = res["original_title"] as! String
            self.mov.desctiption = res["overview"] as! String
            self.movResult.append(self.mov)
            self.resultCount = results.count
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }catch{
        print("Error is occured because of the Json Serialization")
    }
};task.resume()
```

> Problem about the sequence of the downloading

This code works well but there is a problem about downloading images since image url depends on the json url. I want to download images when I download the other datas such as movie title, movie description, etc.

When code runs:

```
print(dataMi)
```

Returns data but...

```
print("2:", dataMi)
```

Returns nil. So what can I do to run that part properly? **Because it also causes an error I could not set my imageview in the cell**

```
 //Error is occured because of the "nil" 
 //self.mov.movImage = UIImage(data:dataMi)!
```

[**Console Screen Shot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODemv.png)

Answer (score 0):

**For your first problem,**

```
let downLoadPicTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlOfthePic!, completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in
    guard let data = data else {print("second"); return}
    dataMi = data
    self.mov.movImage = UIImage(data: dataMi)!
    print(dataMi)
});downLoadPicTask.resume()
print("2:", dataMi)
```

This piece of code is run asynchronously so `print("2:", dataMi)` will execute immediately but `print(dataMi)` will execute after the `dataTask` has completed. So if you print `dataMi` immediately, it will be `nil` of course. After the `dataTask` completes, `dataMi` is not `nil` has contains data.

**For your second problem,** please check if your `urlOfthePic` is correct and accessible.

Comment: In fact, I printed out the `urlOfthePic` the value of the `urlOfthePic` is not nil and it is okay. However, I tried every possible place to set my `self.mov.movImage` to returned `data` every possible place but in the 
 **collectionView** I still cannot see that Image     @chengsam

Comment: Why the UIImage is nil then?

Comment: I already did not understand that part so that I asked that question :D @chengsam

Answer (score 0):

**I solved that problem by myself :D I learned too much staff when I was trying to solve that problem; the best thing that I learned was that: "don't give up.."
The code that I wrote after some time:**

1. **I override my data model and add `poster_path` to my `Movie struct`**
2. **With my JSON process I got the values from the API**
3. **The `movies` array filled with the updated `Movie` objects**
4. **I created an `URL` in the second part which is the `func` from the source code**
5. **Thanks to Dispatch <3 I populated the collectionview with almost *zero latency***

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(true)
   //MARK: JSON
   //get popular films for moviescontroller page

   var components = URLComponents()

   components.scheme = Constanst.API.ApiSchema
   components.host = Constanst.API.ApiHost
   components.path = Constanst.API.ApiPath
   components.path = components.path + Constanst.API.Discover + Constanst.API.Movies
   components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: Constanst.API.ApiKey), URLQueryItem(name: "language", value: "en-US"), URLQueryItem(name: "sort_by", value: "popularity.desc"), URLQueryItem(name: "include_adult", value: "false"), URLQueryItem(name: "include_video", value: "false"),URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: "1")]


   //Url OKé
   let url = components.url

   //Config OKé
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
   request.httpMethod = "GET"

   //Request OKé
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
       guard (error == nil) else{
           print("Error is occures: \(error!)")
           return
       }
       guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode<300 && statusCode>199 else {
           print("There is an error related to your response")
           return
       }
       guard let data = data else {
           print("There is no data")
           return
       }

       //Parsing JSON Oké
       let parsedData : [String:AnyObject]
       do{
           parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
           guard let results = parsedData["results"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else { print("There is a problemGa");return}
           for res in results {
               self.movie.movTitle = res["original_title"] as! String
               self.movie.desctiption = res["overview"] as! String
               self.movie.posterPath = res["poster_path"] as! String
               self.movies.append(self.movie)
           }
       }catch{
           print("Error is occured because of the Json Serialization")
       }
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
       }
   };task.resume()
   ```

   **func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {**

   ```
   let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
   cell.setUpConstraints()

       cell.movieTitle.text = movies[indexPath.row].movTitle
       cell.desc.text = movies[indexPath.row].desctiption
       cell.movieImage.image = movies[indexPath.row].movImage

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url:URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92\(movies[indexPath.row].posterPath)")!), completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in
       guard let imageData = data else {return}
       guard (err == nil) else {print(err!); return}
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           cell.movieImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
       }
   });task.resume()





       return cell
   ```